# Create a default gateway can Route & Forward all traffic to a other socks proxy server

Tags: proxy, iptables, gateway

Create a default gateway can route & Forward traffic to a socks proxy server

Hi, i have:

1 service socks5 proxy at: 1.1.1.1:2

1 server IP 1.1.1.222 want to be a default gateway for LAN 1.1.1.0/24

1 client 1.1.1.x/24 use 1.1.1.222 as its default gateway

---

I want when client 1.1.1.x check its IP Address it will show real ip of socks5 proxy server (route all traffic to that socks server by default gateway)

I was looking for this and getting something like **redsock + iptables** but not successfully configured with Centos 7. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks U!

```
###################################
yum install -y libevent-devel git gcc
mkdir ~/shadowsocks
cd ~/shadowsocks
git clone https://github.com/darkk/redsocks
cd ~/shadowsocks/redsocks
make
cp ~/shadowsocks/redsocks/redsocks /usr/local/bin/ 

###################################
nano /root/redsocks.conf
base {
        log_debug = off;
        log_info = on;
        log = stderr;
        daemon = off;
        redirector = iptables;
}
redsocks {
    /* `local_ip' defaults to 127.0.0.1 for security reasons,
     * use 0.0.0.0 if you want to listen on every interface.
     * `local_*' are used as port to redirect to.
     */
    local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
    local_port = 12345;

    // `ip' and `port' are IP and tcp-port of proxy-server
    ip = 1.1.1.1;
    port = 2;

    // known types: socks4, socks5, http-connect, http-relay
    type = socks5;

    // login = "foobar";
    // password = "baz";
}
###################################


/usr/local/bin/redsocks -c /root/redsocks.conf


###################################


sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens37 -p tcp -j REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens37 -p udp -j REDSOCKS

iptables -A INPUT -i ens37 -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p udp -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345

###################################
```